# Can't find a single stateless Nameprep function

Tags: c++, windows, dll, compilation, stateless

I've been scouring google search for the past 5 days trying to find an appropriate and C++ compatible source or example code that implements a stateless (not needing create(...), init(...), or destroy(...) ) Nameprep function that I can use for IDNA.  Thus far the only thing I've been able to find is from "idnkit-1.0-src" and the RFC.  Problem is, it won't compile with the C++ compiler I'm using (Borland C++ Builder 5 Pro) and it contains a bunch of other functions and fluff that I will never use anyway, making anything I compile with it (if it would compile) a bit bloated.

What I need is just a single simple function that accepts a single parameter (wchar_t *) and outchucks (wchar_t *) that I can pass to the Punycode encoder without a ton of code I'll never use.  I understand that Nameprep is based on Stringprep so it doesn't bother me very much to have to compile Stringprep (and even the other stuff if it would even compile.)

No Ruby nor Python nor Perl nor Java nor JavaScript nor PHP nor anything else.  Just C or C++ please.  It's to be compiled to a 32 bit Windows DLL.  However, if I can interpret another language's source code implementation that would be ok as well.

This is my first trist into IDNA stuff and I'm a bit turned around with all this stuff. Extremely frustrating.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution? http://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/ an option?

Comment: @JimB I've already compiled and distributed the DLL plugin that this was intended for but I don't remember what it was I did.  I'd have to look.